# Inverse Matrix Differential

Tags: matrices, derivatives, differential

Suppose that we are given $g(\Sigma)=\Sigma^{-1}(\mu_0-\mu_1)$, where $\Sigma$ is p by p, and both $\mu_0$ and $\mu_1$ are p by 1.

Now I am hoping to find $\frac{dg}{d\Sigma}$. My current work is using the idea of differential:

$$
dg = (d\Sigma^{-1})(\mu_0-\mu_1) = (-\Sigma^{-1}(d\Sigma)\Sigma^{-1})(\mu_0-\mu_1)
$$

and I am stuck.

I would really appreciate it if you may kindly show me the working steps.

p.s.:I believe the final result should be of dimension $\frac{1}{2}p(p+1)$ by $p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to find the derivative (gradient) of a vector with respect to a matrix. The result will not be a matrix, but a 3rd order tensor!

One way to proceed is to use vectorization (aka column stacking).

And for ease of typing define: 
$\,\,S=\Sigma,\,\,\,W=S^{-1},\,\,\,s={\rm vec}(S),\,\,\,y=(\mu_1-\mu_0)$

Since your differential is correct, let's start from there.
$$\eqalign{
 {\rm vec}(dg) &= {\rm vec}\Big(W\,dS\,Wy\Big) \cr
 dg &= \Big((Wy)^T\otimes W\Big)\,ds \cr
\frac{\partial g}{\partial s} &= (Wy)^T\otimes W \cr
}$$
Another way to proceed is to use higher-order tensors, or else index notation.

In latter notation, the 3rd-order tensor gradient can be written as
$$\eqalign{
G_{ijk} &= \frac{\partial g_{i}}{\partial S_{jk}}
  = W_{ik}W_{jn}y_{n} \cr
}$$
where the repeated index $(n)$ in the final terms implies a summation over that index.

Comment: Yes! This is what I am looking for. Thank you! If possible, could you please kindly tell me where I may obtain more information about derivatives with respect to matrices (like advanced linear algebra?)?

Comment: If you want to learn about vectorization, try *Magnus & Neudecker*. If you're interested in index notation, look for a good textbook in the field of *Continuum Mechanics*.

Comment: Sounds good. Thank you!